# How to login user with username and user_type using device

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, device

I Using Device for login, In login page I have 3 buttons parent,faculty,admin and 3 buttons render the same login form. If i click parent button and trying to login means it would allow only parent users not allowing other user_types.?
How to achieve this?

My login form: (common to all user_type)

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url:session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
<p><%= f.text_field :login ,placeholder: 'Username or Email' %></p>
<p><%= f.password_field :password ,placeholder: 'Password'%></p>
<p><button type="submit">SIGN IN </button></p>
<% end %>
```

Application controller:

```
before_action :authenticate_user!  
def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:login, :username,  :password, :remember_me) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:username,  :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password) }
  end
```

Comment: Use different functions in the click events of those buttons, and write your logic accordingly

Comment: We need more info there. How's your form? The form submit to the same controller? You can change the path of the controller?

Comment: Same form for all users. Only button is different.

Comment: I just wanna know so that I can give you better advise. How are you separating your user types?. How have you set it up so that you can tell xyz username or xyz email is from an admin a teacher or a parent?.

Comment: In user table user_types are separated by user_types field, in that field user_types like admin, parent, student are defined.